# css selector for element having a descendant with specific properties.

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an element having a descendant with CSS.

Basically if I have a

```
<div id="looking_for_this">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="must_have_this_class">text</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="looking_for_this_too">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="must_have_this_class">other text</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm looking to find the divs (I marked them with an id) based on the fact that they have a descendant with a class: `must_have_this_class`.

I found the experimental pseudo-class [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), which I would use like:

```
 div:has(.must_have_this_class) { ... }
```

finding the two divs in the example. Though this is an experimental feature, and no browsers support it as of Oct 2018.

Comment: Browsers do not support such a selector. https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas

You can easily do that with javascript tho.

Comment: there is no parent selector in css. You will need JS for this task

Comment: You can write very simple jquery code to select parent and then set a style for it

Comment: I'm using this with a styling extension for chrome, I don't have any javascript available there. Just CSS